# Why is it selecting this file?

Tags: regex, linq

I have the following statement:

```
Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "A*.pdf")
.Where(file => Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(file), "[Aa][i-lI-L].*"))
.Skip((pageNum - 1) * pageSize)
.Take(pageSize)
.Select(path => new FileInfo(path))
.ToArray()
```

My problems is that the above statement also finds the file "Adali.pdf" which it should not - but i cannot figure out why.

The above statement should only select files starting with a, and where the second letter is in the range i-l.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it matches `Adali` taking 3rd and 4th characters (`al`):

```
Adali
  --
```

Try using `^` in your regex which allows looking for start of the string ([regex cheatsheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)):

```
Regex.IsMatch(..., "^[Aa][i-lI-L].*")
```

Also I doubt you need asterisk at all.

PS: As a sidenote let me notice that this question doesn't seem to be written that good. You should try debugging this code yourself and particularly you should try checking your regex against your cases without LINQ. I'm sure there is nothing to do here with LINQ (the tag you have in your question), but the issue is about regular expressions (which you didn't mention in tags at all).

Answer (score 0):

You are not anchoring the string. This makes the regex match the `al` in `Adali.pdf`.

Change the regex to `^[Aa][i-lI-L].*` You can do just `^[Aa][i-lI-L]` if you don't need anything besides matching.

Answer (score 0):

You should to do this

```
var f = Directory.GetFiles(tb_Path.Text, "A*.pdf").Where(file => Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(file), "[Aa][i-lI-L].pdf")).ToArray();
```

When you call ".*" Adali accept in Regex